# How to add an AngularJS ng-click option to a javascript generated button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I'm using bootstrap Modal window for adding a new member for my site, to open it, since I'm using AngularJS, I have to add a `ng-click="open()"` parameter to a button, but since a plugin I'm using is generating buttons using JS, I don't really see how I can add it to the JS code, it looks like this:

```
case "add":
    var itemZ = new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig();
    itemZ .title = "Z Title";
    itemZ .description = "Z Description";
    itemZ .image = "http://www.basicprimitives.com/demo/images/photos/z.png";
    data.context.items.push(itemZ);

    jQuery(".basicdiagram").orgDiagram("update", primitives.orgdiagram.UpdateMode.Refresh);
    break;
```

so is there a way I could sneak in that ng-click property?

Comment: I'm not sure but did you try to use primitives.common.attr? http://www.basicprimitives.com/index.php?option=com_local&view=local&Itemid=44#primitives.common.attr

Comment: I had a go with it, but, as I believe after the result, that's not function I'm looking for.

Comment: It's probably not answering your question completely, but here a way to reach an angular scope function from classic javascript code (that way, you can simulate the ng-click):
/* document.getElementById('page-data') => angular view container */

angular.element( document.getElementById('page-data') ).scope().$apply( function(scope) { scope.yourScopeMethod(); });

Comment: I believe your real problem is that you're using a plugin to generate buttons. Why? Angular can almost certainly do whatever you're doing in a much better fashion. I usually hear of someone trying to use a jQuery plugin that they could have re-written in angular from scratch in 10 minutes.